# OpenGL Geometry Shader Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, opengl, geometry-shader

I'm trying to get a simple pass through geometry shader to work under Mac OS X 10.6.  The code compiles and links without problem, but for some reason no geometry is being drawn to the screen.  Here's my shader code:

```
#version 120
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4: enable

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[0];
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

If anybody could help I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out, the problem wasn't in the shader code at all.  Apparently, when using version 120 in a geometry shader, you have to set the input and output types as follows:

```
glProgramParameteriEXT(shaderProgramID, GL_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_TYPE_EXT, GL_POINTS);
glProgramParameteriEXT(shaderProgramID, GL_GEOMETRY_VERTICES_OUT_EXT, GL_POINTS);
```

After that everything worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A geometry shader works on entire primitives.  Yours looks like it would only be suitable for points.  If you are not passing in points you need to process all `gl_VerticesIn` (count) vertices.

Comment: The eventual plan is to have the shader process one point into more complex geometry.  Right now I'm only passing through individual points.